# Hide divs based on two select elements numerically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just a little bit stuck at the moment I know how to show and hide divs using jQuery, one thing I have not been able to find out is how to hide and show divs based on there numerical value.

Here is a small example of my code:

```
<div class="makes MERCEDES-BENZ" style="display: block;">
  <div class="listing-container">
    <h3 class="price-listing">£10,989</h3>
  </div>
    <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
      <li value="49695">Mileage: 49,695</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see this HTML contains a h3 with the class of 'price-listing', I want to show and hide the div with the class of 'makes' based on whether the 'price-listing' div contains the value that the form is filtering. Just so you know there is a list of these 'make' divs on my page with different values.

Right so to my form I currently have this form:

```
<form class="car-finder-container" method="GET" action="used-cars.php">
    <select class="form-control select-box price-min">
        <option value="min-price">Min price</option>
        <option value="0">£0</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <select class="form-control select-box price-max">
        <option value="max-price">Max price</option>
        <option value="0">£0</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

So the first select element is to hide the values in the h3 that have a smaller numerical value than the option selected.

The second select element is to hide any h3s with values higher than the numerical value option selected.

I could give the price a value if one is needed just like I have with the li in the first example.

Could anyone show me a code example on how this might be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the JavaScript you're attempting to use so far, and point out where it's not working as intended?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Typically it's expected that you've tried something and are coming here with a more specific question. "Can I haz code" doesn't usually sit well. Maybe put yours in a fiddle for us to look at. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Shouldn't this sentence `The second select element is to hide any h3s with values lower than the numerical value option selected.` be  `higher than`?

Comment: Yes sorry I will edit that

Comment: What are these select option supposed to do:<option value="min-price">Min price</option> <option value="max-price">Max price</option>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var min = $('select.price-min').val();
    var max = $('select.price-max').val();
    $('div.makes').show();
    $('h3.price-listing').filter(function () {
        var price = +$(this).text().substring(1).replace(',', '');
        if (price < min || price > max) return true;
    }).closest('div.makes').hide();
})
```

```js
$('select').change(function () {
    var min = $('select.price-min').val();
    var max = $('select.price-max').val();
    $('div.makes').show();
    $('h3.price-listing').filter(function () {
        var price = +$(this).text().substring(1).replace(',', '');
        if (price < min || price > max) return true;
    }).closest('div.makes').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="car-finder-container" method="GET" action="used-cars.php">
    <select class="form-control select-box price-min">
        <option value="min-price">Min price</option>
        <option value="0">£0</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
        <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
        <option value="1500">£1,500</option>
        <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
        <option value="2500">£2,500</option>
        <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
        <option value="3500">£3,500</option>
        <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
        <option value="4500">£4,500</option>
        <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
        <option value="5500">£5,500</option>
        <option value="6000">£6,000</option>
        <option value="6500">£6,500</option>
        <option value="7000">£7,000</option>
        <option value="7500">£7,500</option>
        <option value="8000">£8,000</option>
        <option value="8500">£8,500</option>
        <option value="9000">£9,000</option>
        <option value="9500">£9,500</option>
        <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
        <option value="11000">£11,000</option>
        <option value="12000">£12,000</option>
        <option value="13000">£13,000</option>
        <option value="14000">£14,000</option>
        <option value="15000">£15,000</option>
        <option value="16000">£16,000</option>
        <option value="17000">£17,000</option>
        <option value="18000">£18,000</option>
        <option value="19000">£19,000</option>
        <option value="20000">£20,000</option>
        <option value="22500">£22,500</option>
        <option value="25000">£25,000</option>
        <option value="27500">£27,500</option>
        <option value="30000">£30,000</option>
        <option value="35000">£35,000</option>
        <option value="40000">£40,000</option>
        <option value="45000">£45,000</option>
        <option value="50000">£50,000</option>
        <option value="55000">£55,000</option>
        <option value="60000">£60,000</option>
        <option value="65000">£65,000</option>
        <option value="70000">£70,000</option>
        <option value="75000">£75,000</option>
        <option value="100000">£100,000</option>
        <option value="250000">£250,000</option>
        <option value="500000">£500,000</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control select-box price-max">
        <option value="max-price">Max price</option>
        <option value="0">£0</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
        <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
        <option value="1500">£1,500</option>
        <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
        <option value="2500">£2,500</option>
        <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
        <option value="3500">£3,500</option>
        <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
        <option value="4500">£4,500</option>
        <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
        <option value="5500">£5,500</option>
        <option value="6000">£6,000</option>
        <option value="6500">£6,500</option>
        <option value="7000">£7,000</option>
        <option value="7500">£7,500</option>
        <option value="8000">£8,000</option>
        <option value="8500">£8,500</option>
        <option value="9000">£9,000</option>
        <option value="9500">£9,500</option>
        <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
        <option value="11000">£11,000</option>
        <option value="12000">£12,000</option>
        <option value="13000">£13,000</option>
        <option value="14000">£14,000</option>
        <option value="15000">£15,000</option>
        <option value="16000">£16,000</option>
        <option value="17000">£17,000</option>
        <option value="18000">£18,000</option>
        <option value="19000">£19,000</option>
        <option value="20000">£20,000</option>
        <option value="22500">£22,500</option>
        <option value="25000">£25,000</option>
        <option value="27500">£27,500</option>
        <option value="30000">£30,000</option>
        <option value="35000">£35,000</option>
        <option value="40000">£40,000</option>
        <option value="45000">£45,000</option>
        <option value="50000">£50,000</option>
        <option value="55000">£55,000</option>
        <option value="60000">£60,000</option>
        <option value="65000">£65,000</option>
        <option value="70000">£70,000</option>
        <option value="75000">£75,000</option>
        <option value="100000">£100,000</option>
        <option value="250000">£250,000</option>
        <option value="500000">£500,000</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div class="makes MERCEDES-BENZ" style="display: block;">
    <div class="listing-container">
         <h3 class="price-listing">£15,989</h3>

    </div>
    <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
        <li value="49695">Mileage: 49,695</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="makes MERCEDES-BENZ" style="display: block;">
    <div class="listing-container">
         <h3 class="price-listing">£10,989</h3>

    </div>
    <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
        <li value="49695">Mileage: 49,695</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="makes MERCEDES-BENZ" style="display: block;">
    <div class="listing-container">
         <h3 class="price-listing">£25,989</h3>

    </div>
    <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
        <li value="49695">Mileage: 49,695</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great I do have one question though, if you visit my live site: http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.php

And then press the 'Make' tab, select a make and then change the price why is the 'Make' select element cancelled out when the price is selected any idea how I could stop this? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't cancel anything for me.

Comment: Strange, so let's say you select "Vauxhall" then you select a price it doesn't cancel out the "Vauxhall" select element and show all other manufacturers?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select id="priceMax" class="form-control select-box price-max">
            <option value="max-price">Max price</option>
            <option value="0">£0</option>
            <option value="500">£500</option>
        </select>

<select id="priceMin" class="form-control select-box price-min">
        <option value="min-price">Min price</option>
        <option value="0">£0</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
    </select>





$("#priceMax").change(function () {
        var limit = $(this).val();
        var h3Arr = $("h3");

        h3Arr.each(function () {

            if (parseInt($(this).text().substring(1, $(this).text().length).replace(/,/g, '')) > parseInt(limit)) {
                $(this).closest("div[class='makes MERCEDES-BENZ']").hide();
            }else
            {
                $(this).closest("div[class='makes MERCEDES-BENZ']").show();
            }
        })
    })



 $("#priceMin").change(function () {
                var limit = $(this).val();
                var h3Arr = $("h3");

                h3Arr.each(function () {

                    if (parseInt($(this).text().substring(1, $(this).text().length).replace(/,/g, ''))<parseInt(limit)) {
                        $(this).closest("div[class='makes MERCEDES-BENZ']").hide();
                    }else
                    {
                        $(this).closest("div[class='makes MERCEDES-BENZ']").show();
                    }
                })
            })
```

Comment: This is wrong for at least two reasons: (1) The OP needs to hide the entire `div`, not just the `h3`. (2) It's comparing a "500" to "£10,989"; those need to be converted to simple numbers beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've had a go at implementing it into my live site with no luck, been trying for the past 20 mins. Don't suppose you can spot anything can you that might be causing it to go wrong? Just press on 'Price Range' and the select elements will display: http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.php

Comment: I cannot find currently the the event handler bindings on the website.

Comment: `parseInt('10,989')` will return `10`. Gotta strip out that comma. Maybe slip in a `.replace(/,/g, '')` after the `substring()`.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for your requirement.

```js
$(".price-min").change(function(){
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $("h3.price-listing").filter(function(){
    if(selVal > parseInt($(this).html().replace(',','').replace('£',''))){
        $(this).closest('.makes').hide();
    }
        });
    });


$(".price-max").change(function(){
    var selVal = $(this).val();
   $("h3.price-listing").filter(function(){
    if(selVal < parseInt($(this).html().replace(',','').replace('£',''))){
        $(this).closest('.makes').hide();
    }
});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="makes MERCEDES-BENZ" style="display: block;">
  <div class="listing-container">
    <h3 class="price-listing">£10,989</h3>
  </div>
    <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
      <li value="49695">Mileage: 49,695</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form class="car-finder-container" method="GET" action="used-cars.php">
    <select class="form-control select-box  price-min">
        <option value="min-price">Min price</option>
        <option value="0">£0</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
        <option value="300">£300</option>
        <option value="100">£100</option>
        <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
        <option value="11000">£11,000</option>    </select>
    <select class="form-control select-box price-max">
        <option value="max-price">Max price</option>
        <option value="0">£0</option>
        <option value="500">£500</option>
        <option value="300">£300</option>
        <option value="100">£100</option>
        <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
        <option value="11000">£11,000</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e1g0dwsb/2/